# Passing CloudKit records from TableViewController A to TableViewControllerB on segue with dynamic prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, segue, cloudkit

I'm able to populate TableViewController A with records from CloudKit (`var restaurants: [CKRecord] = []`) but not sure how to **pass a subset of [CKRecord] onto TableViewController B since both controllers have dynamic prototype cells** and have their respective view cells defined `as UITableViewCell`. Further, the **segue should only be triggered when the user taps the navigation item on TableViewController A** (not when cell is selected).

Here's how I've implemented cellForRowAt

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as! RestuarantViewCell

   // Configure the cell...
    let restaurant = restaurants[indexPath.row]
    cell.RestNameLabel?.text = restaurant.object(forKey: "name") as? String
    cell.RestDescLabel?.text = restaurant.object(forKey: "desc") as? String

    if let image = restaurant.object(forKey: "image"), let imageAsset = image as? CKAsset {
        if let imageData = try?Data.init(contentsOf: imageAsset.fileURL) {
            cell.RestImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

1. When a user performs a leading swipe, add that item to a list (`var list: [CKRecord] = []`)

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

```
let addAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Save") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
    //Add to list
    self.list.append(self.restaurants[indexPath.row])
    print(self.list)

    //Delete row and reload tableView i.e. tableView.reloadData()
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    //Call completion handler to dismiss the action button
    completionHandler(true)
}

//Configuring delete button
addAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 76, green: 217, blue: 100)

//Create button for user swipe
let swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [addAction])

return swipeConfiguration
```

}

2. This list is only visible when the user tap the navigation item on TableViewController A (not when cell is selected). Segue `"showList"` has been implemented in storyboard from nav item to TableViewController B.

In short, TableViewController B is a list of restaurant (name, image) saves from TableViewController A

Should I use `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` or perhaps save this swipe to the cloud and fetch it again in TableViewController B?

Appreciate your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would use `prepare for segue` as you've mentioned. Make the `restaurants` array a class property on both table `A` and table `B`.

Something like this:

```
//Table View Controller A
class TableViewA: UIViewController{
  var restaurants = [CKRecord]()

  override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "NameThisInYourStoryboard"{
      let vc = segue.destinationController as! TableViewB
      vc.restaurants = self.restaurants //Pass the data
    }
  }
}

//Table View Controller B
class TableViewB: UIViewController{
  var restaurants = [CKRecord]()
}
```

This all presupposes that you set up the delegate and datasource of your controllers, and define the segue in your storyboard from `A`'s table row tap to show table `B`.